# Android dynamic layout click problems

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, click

i create a dynamic view ( linearlayout ) with

`table.addView(view, layoutParams);`

I want when I click on view1 the background color turns white,
when I click on view2  the background color of view1 turns black and  the background color of view2 turns white, and if I click on view3  the background color of view2 turns black and  the background color of view3 turns white ...

[image]

```
    private void addToRow(int rowID, TimeCard timecard, int offset) {

    LayoutParams tlparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TIMECARD_WIDTH,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    tlparams.setMargins((int) offset, 150-50*rowID, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("rowID=  "+50*rowID);
    View v = timecard.getView(context);

    v.setOnClickListener(this);


    rows.get(rowID).addView(v, tlparams);

}


private void addRowsToTable() {

    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (LinearLayout row : rows) {
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //table is an absolutlayout and i add many row in this layout
        table.addView(row, layoutParams);

    }

    tableNavbar.addView(llnavBar, layoutParams);

}
        @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cadre_blanc);

    TextView t1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tc_title);
    t1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 139, 221));


}
```

how can i do this please??

Comment: post some code so that i can help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Just change the background color onClick.

Comment: Which of them are view1, view2, view3? You mean the clicking on the table rows?

Comment: @Indiandroid hi I add some code (with the onClick I change the view BackgroundResource when I click but when I click it changes vue2 BackgroundResource and vue1 remains with the same BackgroundResource) I just need the last view click changes the BackgroundResource also

Comment: @AmulyaKhare i add picture